# Auto Generated HTML - Adobe GoLive Script

Tags: php, javascript, html

Alright so a client of mine has about 40 auto generated html pages. This is all done through a JS lib called Adobe GoLive JavaScript Library. I'm not sure what happened but this has stopped working now during the site move. I really don't want to even try and fix this because I just don't like the idea of auto generating an HTML page off of one click of a link. My question is is there a JavaScript library out there that is still active that does this or should I just use PHP to make these pages?

Comment: I would always go with PHP over JavaScript when applicable; clients can turn JavaScript off which would break the whole site, however a PHP script would run irregardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP.

Reasons:

- Javascript can be turned off on the client side.
- PHP is supported on almost all web servers,
- and will render the page regardless of what the client has.
- PHP is quite easy to learn and has lots of documentation and tutorials surrounding it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I already know PHP but I was looking for a faster approach but this will have to do

Comment: @stewbydoo - You could use a CMS like Wordpress or Drupal to make it faster.